# Gel all image from certain post type

Tags: attachments, gallery, media-library, post-type

I've found similar questions here, however I can't modify the answers to get images only from a certain post type - as the post type in those examples are "attachment" and not the name of a custom post type.

Is there a way to declare a custom post type argument as well?

[Similar question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9561/get-all-post-attachments-except-featured-image),
[another similar question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11662/get-all-images-in-media-gallery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code in your template.

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'custom-post', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
if( $query->have_posts() ){
    while($query->have_posts()){
        $query->the_post();
        $image_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_parent' => get_the_ID() ) );
        while( $image_query->have_posts() ) {
            $image_query->the_post();
            echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_the_ID() );
        }
    }
}
```

Replace `custom-post` with you custom post type.

Comment: Thanks. It's not just working, but it seems to exclude post thumbnails as well. Great.

Comment: Correction: post thumbnails are not excluded.