# Get all images from posts with maximum number and without featured image

Tags: post-thumbnails, attachments, gallery

I recently asked a question on how to get all images from all posts - and I got a working answer, but unfortunately the code gets post-thumnbnails as well, and I didn't find a way to limit the number of queried images.

[My last question is here.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35338/gel-all-image-from-certain-post-type)

Thanks.

```
<?php
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
if( $query->have_posts() ){
while($query->have_posts()){
$query->the_post();
$thumb_ID = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
$image_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'exclude' => $thumbID, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_parent' => get_the_ID() ) );
while( $image_query->have_posts() ) {
$image_query->the_post();
echo '<dl class="gallery-item"><dt class="gallery-icon"><a rel="shadowbox[sbalbum-1];player=img;" href="' , the_permalink() , '">', wp_get_attachment_image( get_the_ID() ) , '</a></dt></dl>';
}
}
}
?>
```

Changing the number of the posts_per_page arg in the image_query has no effect, on the number of attachments displayed.

I came up with the following, working code with the help of @Bainternet:

```
<?php
$image_count = 0;
$max_images = of_get_option('thumbs_number');
$Posts = new WP_Query();
$Posts->query('post_type=post&post_status=publish&posts_per_page=-1');
    while ($Posts->have_posts()) : $Posts->the_post();    
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'exclude' => get_post_thumbnail_id($id)
    );

$attachments = get_posts( $args );
    if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
            if ($image_count < $max_images){
echo '<dl class="gallery-item"><dt class="gallery-icon"><a rel="shadowbox[sbalbum-1];player=img;" href="' , the_permalink() , '">';
echo wp_get_attachment_link( $attachment->ID, 'footer_thumbs' );
echo '</a></dt></dl>';
$image_count = $image_count + 1;
        }
    }
}
endwhile;?>
```

Comment: Post alink to a pastebin containing the array of results from your query. Don't have a test setup for this right now.

Comment: Updated my Q with the code I'm trying to tweak, as you can see,  it echos every every single post attachments including post-thumbnails.

Comment: No, I can't see. I only see you adding markup. PLEASE make a `print_r` of the resulting array, put it into a pastebin and link here. I'm not going to guess around.

Comment: Like this: http://pastebin.com/VYBxytvL ?

Comment: Close :) Could you wrap it into something like `echo '<pre>'; print_r( $image_query ); echo '</pre>';` so it's more readable? Thanks!

Comment: http://pastebin.com/GGW9V7Ua

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$image_count = 0;
$max_images = 10;  //set this to the max number of images you want.
$ids = get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ,'fields' =>'ids') );
if (count($ids) > 0){
    foreach ($ids as $id){
        while ($image_count < $max_images){
            $args = array(
                'post_type'   => 'attachment',
                'numberposts' => -1,
                'post_status' => null,
                'post_parent' => $id,
                'exclude'     => get_post_thumbnail_id($id)
            );
            $attachments = get_posts( $args );
            if ( $attachments ) {
                foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
                    if ($image_count < $max_images){
                        echo '<dl class="gallery-item">
                            <dt class="gallery-icon">
                                <a rel="shadowbox[sbalbum-1];player=img;" href="' . get_permalink($attachment->ID) . '">'. wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID ) . '</a>
                            </dt>
                         </dl>';
                         $image_count = $image_count + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which is about the same as the example in the codex ([Show All attachments for the current post beside Thumb](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id#Show_All_attachments_for_the_current_post_beside_Thumb) ) combined with your code (almost) to get All attachments for all posts.

Mind the first query is changed to a `get_posts()` function with the parameter `fields` set to ids to get only the ids of the posts since you don't really need the rest of the data, and is much much faster.

Comment: With the following code I'm getting: Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in...

Comment: Isn't the second while loop going to push the counter to the end before the outer while loop has a chance to make a second iteration though?

Comment: Yes but that is why its there.

Comment: It'not working. Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in../wp-includes/query.php on line 1924

Comment: Ok. I got the code working and it seems that t31os saw the problem with the it: I'm getting the same image 10x.

Comment: ok i updated the code and replace the second while with an if

Comment: Thanks but, still no luck: maximum execution time exceeded in...  query.php on line 1924

Comment: @Bainternet I played around your code and and it seems to be working now. I cannot answer my own question so I copied the working snippet to my question.

Comment: @elbatron, you can answer your own questions

Comment: I started looking for the same thing and ended up here :) ...