# Count all images of a certain post type

Tags: custom-post-types, attachments, images

I followed two posts related to my query. One was about the [number of images attached to a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485011/how-do-i-show-the-number-of-images-attached-to-a-post-on-the-image-attachment-pa) and second about [showing all images of a certain post type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35338/gel-all-image-from-certain-post-type). I tried to combine the two codes in the following way but it didn't help:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'gallery', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
if( $query->have_posts() ){
    while($query->have_posts()){
        $query->the_post();
        $attachments = get_children( array( 'post_parent' => $parent->ID, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'menu_order ID' ) );
        $count = count( $attachments );
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me in counting all images attached to a certain post type?

Comment: What have you done so far? Please post some code.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: you need to declare `$count` outside of your `while` loop and then within the loop add each iteration to it, like `$count += count( $attachments );` to end up with the total.

Comment: That doesn't work. It inflates the count to much more than the total number of images in the Media library. I just want the number of images attached to the all the posts of type 'gallery'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting this in your functions file, and then place `<?php $attachment_count; ?>` in a template file.

```
function attachment_count() {
global $post;
    //Get all attachments
    $attachments = get_posts( array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    ) );

    $att_count = 0;
    if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
            // Check for the post type based on individual attachment's parent
            if ( 'gallery' == get_post_type($attachment->post_parent) ) {
                $att_count = $att_count + 1;
            }
        }
        echo $att_count;
    }
}
```