# Get images only from a certain post type

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, gallery

I implemented this code on my site and it works.

[enter link description here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35338/gel-all-image-from-certain-post-type?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But it works only once, I mean then if added other posts the code does not work do not get images from the posts.
Even when I clear the cache & cookies.
It is necessary to put the WP_Query or wp_reset_postdata or other ?

Comment: please edit your question and make it self contained and readable

Answer (score -1):

You need to put *wp_reset_postdata()* after each while loop. It is best practice to put after each loop. Once you put, you will get images data for each custom post type.

```
<?php

    // The Query
    $query1 = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $query1->have_posts() ) {
        // The Loop
        while ( $query1->have_posts() ) {
            $query1->the_post();
            echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';

            //print post thumbnail
            echo get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), 'thumbnail' ); 


            //get post thumb url
            $featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'full'); 

        }

        /* Restore original Post Data 
         * NB: Because we are using new WP_Query we aren't stomping on the 
         * original $wp_query and it does not need to be reset with 
         * wp_reset_query(). We just need to set the post data back up with
         * wp_reset_postdata().
         */
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }

    /* The 2nd Query (without global var) */
    $query2 = new WP_Query( $args2 );

    if ( $query2->have_posts() ) {
        // The 2nd Loop
        while ( $query2->have_posts() ) {
            $query2->the_post();

            //print post thumbnail
            echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $query2->post->ID, 'thumbnail' ); 


            //get post thumb url
            $featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($query2->post->ID,'full'); 
            echo '<li>' . get_the_title( $query2->post->ID ) . '</li>';
        }

        // Restore original Post Data
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Try to understand wordpress loop system 
 https://digwp.com/2011/05/loops/

Comment: i am confused, what does this code have to do with images?

Comment: Above code describe use of wp_reset_postdata() to put after each loop. If it does not put then we can't get proper data in each loop including images.

Comment: that is just not correct in the context of this question, and in any case the code is not relevant to the question and will just confuse people

Comment: .... no point in answering if you do not bother to read and understand the question :(

Comment: @MarkKaplun if you read question again, then he asked about to use 'wp_reset_postdata' or not while using WP_query, so I answered his question with example. What's wrong in this?

Comment: Thank AddWeb Solution for the wp_reset_postdata() code now I know how to use it.
Mark this code enabled me to achieve the following goal, gets the image from a post and with a @keyframes I did a slidershow without javascript.

Comment: bad answer to bad question, just a normal day around here :(